# System's flash player instead of chrome's version

Tags: google-chrome, window, adobe-flash

Ever since chrome updated, I became unable to use my system's flash player...  Instead, I am forced to use pepper flash which uses 99% CPU when playing youtube videos.

Only one flash player is listed when I go to chrome://plugins and expand details.

How do I get chrome to use the system's flash player again?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Flash Player with Google Chrome](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html) KB article:

> **How can I run the system plug-in, debugger or alternate versions of
>   Flash Player in Google Chrome?**
>
> Developers using Google Chrome can download and install a separate
>   debugger or prerelease version of Flash Player as a system plug-in.
>   Advanced users wanting to install a new version of Flash Player before
>   they receive an automatic update through Chrome can install and use a
>   separate system plug-in.
>
> However, **Adobe recommends that non-developer Chrome users use Flash
>   Player integrated with their browser**. Using manually installed
>   versions of Flash Player, by following the steps below, means that
>   users no longer benefit from the automatic Flash Player updates that
>   Chrome provides.
>
> To install and use an alternate version of Flash Player:
>
> 1. Download and install the appropriate system plug-in. This plug-in could be a [debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), prerelease, or [release version](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?fpchrome) of Flash Player.
>      (Archived release versions of the system plug-in are found [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html).)
> 2. Type “about:plugins” (without quotation marks) into the address bar at the top of a Chrome browser window.
> 3. Click “Details” at the upper-right corner of the page.
> 4. Find the “Flash” (or “Shockwave Flash”) listing for the **integrated** plug-in on the page and click the corresponding “Disable” button. To
>      identify the integrated plug-in, see the table of plug-in filenames
>      below.
> 5. Find the “Flash” (or “Shockwave Flash”) listing for the **system** plug-in on the page and click the corresponding “Enable” button. To
>      identify the system plug-in, see the table of plug-in filenames below.
> 6. Close all Chrome windows and restart the browser.
>
> Chrome uses the installed system plug-in. To confirm the version of
>   Flash Player that is currently running in your browser, see [Find Flash
>   Player version](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html) (tn_15507).

Table of plugin names:

```
Platform  Integrated Plug-in        System Plug-in
--------  ------------------------  -------------------
Windows   pepflashplayer.dll        NPSWF32.dll
Mac OS    PepperFlashPlayer.plugin  Flash Player.plugin
Linux     libpepflashplayer.so      libflashplayer.so
```

Comment: I'm running Snow Leopard, which no longer gets Chrome updates, so I tried to follow these instructions to switch to the system plugin since a critical update was released today. But I don't see the system plugin in `about:plugins`. I tried restarting Chrome in case it only checks the system directory at startup, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Chrome://plugins and press the +Details button to expand details of all the plugins.
   [image: Chrome://plugins]
2. In the Adobe Flash Player section, find the location of the plugin. It should be in your Userdata folder. Copy that location but take off the file on the end. In my case, I would take off "pepflashplayer.dll" and I would have copied "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\23.0.0.207\", without the quotation marks.
   [image: location]
3. Close Chrome.
4. Paste the directory that you copied into explorer and delete the folder that you are in. In my case, I would delete the folder "23.0.0.207".
5. Apply the read only property to the folder above it so Google Chrome can't reinstall Flash Player. In my case, I would apply the read only property to the "PepperFlash" folder.

To check if this worked properly, go back to Chrome://plugins and check Adobe flash player. The plugin location should change to another location. 
[image: location changed]